# Exclude certain entries and its children from navigation

Tags: entries, navigation, children

I need to split up a navigaton tree. So I try to exclude certain pages from a structure based navigation tree PLUS their children automatically, but don’t seem to get it.

```
{% nav page in craft.entries.section('pages').id('and,not 3,not 4,not 5') %}
```

Excluding certain entries like this works.

But:

```
{% nav page in craft.entries.section('pages').descendantOf('and,not 3,not 4,not 5') %}
```

… doesn’t return anything of course, because descendantOf needs one exact ID. But how could I manage to exclude entries 3, 4 and 5 AND all their children from the navigation without calling the exact IDs of all the children?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it’s true that the `descendantOf` param doesn’t allow to pass in multiple entries, you probably need to work around that issue and grab the descendants for each parent entry individually.

```
{% set parentIds = [3, 4, 5] %}
{% set excludeIds = parentIds %}

{% for parentId in parentIds %}
    {% set ids = craft.entries.descendantOf(parentId).ids() %}
    {% set excludeIds = excludeIds|merge(ids) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set idParam = 'and, not ' ~ excludeIds|join(', not ') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('pages').id(idParam) %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!I actually don’t know for sure because of decendantOf and multiple entries. But passing multiple entries simply didn’t work so I assumed the rest.